# tkinter reading checkbutton values added through a for loop

Tags: python, loops, checkbox, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a menu test for the employees at my restaurant.  The plan is for menu items to loop through "***Loop items here***" at which time they select the correct checkbuttons (ingredients) and then click the "***submit and continue button***".  When they click the submit button I first need to read the on and off values of the checkbuttons to determine which items they have selected, then compare those to the correct answers that I defined in a dictionary of lists, then clear all checkbuttons and whether the answer is wrong or right the program will continue on and I will eventually have a results screen but right now I am stuck on how to read the checkbutton on and off values.  I am simply trying to print the selected veggies right now and cant figure it out.

I think it has to do with the fact they are in different methods and also the fact that they were added in a loop?  I am not sure exactly but I know my code is trying to read the wrong thing and any help would be greeeeatly appreciated!

Sorry for the lengthy question I just thought it would be beneficial to give you as much info as possible to understand what I am trying to do..

[image: screenshoot]

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()
        self.parent.title("Wahoos Menu Test")
        self.create_buttons()

    global count
    count = -1

    def create_buttons(self):
        for r in range(20):
            for c in range(14):
                Label(self, text='',
                    borderwidth=0).grid(row=r,column=c)
        B = Button(self, text ="Begin Exam", relief=RIDGE, fg="black", command= self.on_button_press).grid(row=19, column=7)
        L = Label(self, text="What comes in the following", fg="blue").grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.veg = ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Cheese', 'Ahee Rice', 'Brown Rice', 'Banzai Veg', 'Red Cabbage', 'Black Beans', 'Cajun White Beans']
        self.vegboxes = []
        self.opt = []
        c = 1
        for ve in self.veg:
            c +=1
            self.v = IntVar()
            self.vegboxes.append(self.v)
            vo = Checkbutton(self, text=ve, variable=self.v, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=c, column=11, sticky=W)

    def on_button_press(self):
        global count
        count = count + 1
        menuItems = {'nft': ['cabbage', 'cheese', 'corn', 'nf', 'salsa'],
        'nckt': ['lettuce', 'cheese', 'corn', 'nck', 'salsa']}
        menu = ['blackened fish taco', 'wahoos chicken salad']
        if count == len(menu):
            C = Button(self, text ="           Your Done!          ", relief=RIDGE, fg="black").grid(row=19, column=7)
        else:
            m = Label(self, text=menu[count], fg="black").grid(row=7, column=0)
            C = Button(self, text ="Submit and Continue", relief=RIDGE, fg="black", command= self.read_checks).grid(row=19, column=7)
    def read_checks(self):
        for v in self.veg:
            if self.v == 1:
                print(self.veg[v])


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Side-note: One of the benefits of a class is that you can stick something like self.count in the `__init__` thereby avoiding the global keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a dictionary and have each key be the Checkbutton's label,
and have the value be the state ["Control Variable".](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/control-variables.html)
Then you would check the state with the Control Variable's get() method as shown in the example below.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.buttonDic = {
        'Brown Rice':0,
        'Banzai Veg':0,
        'Red Cabbage':0,
        'Black Beans':0
        }

        for key in self.buttonDic:
            self.buttonDic[key] = tk.IntVar()
            aCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=key,
                                            variable=self.buttonDic[key])
            aCheckButton.grid(sticky='w')

        submitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                                        command=self.query_checkbuttons)
        submitButton.grid()

    def query_checkbuttons(self):
        for key, value in self.buttonDic.items():
            state = value.get()
            if state != 0:
                print(key)
                self.buttonDic[key].set(0)

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

This approach allows you to create and analyze the Checkbuttons with one dictionary.
Note the use of items() in `for key, value in self.buttonDic.items():`
which is needed to prevent:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

More information on the Checkbutton widget and it's variable can be found: [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

---

I'm going to include my first attempt which was based on
the Checkbutton widget's `onvalue` and `offvalue`,
in case it helps someone understand Control Variables a bit more.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.bRiceV = tk.StringVar()
        bRice = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Brown Rice",variable=self.bRiceV,
                                    onvalue="Brown Rice", offvalue="Off")
        bRice.pack()

        self.bVegV = tk.StringVar()
        bVeg = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Banzai Veg",variable=self.bVegV,
                                    onvalue="Banzai Veg", offvalue="Off")
        bVeg.pack()

        self.varList = [self.bRiceV, self.bVegV]

        submitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                                command=self.query_checkbuttons)
        submitButton.pack()

    def query_checkbuttons(self):
        for var in self.varList:
            value = var.get()
            if value != 'Off':
                print(value)
                var.set('Off')

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!  So frustrating I had something so similar to this earlier that I was trying to use but couldn't get it nailed down.  I really appreciate it.  Now its on to figuring out how to store them so I can compare them to my dictionary of lists...